# suitable packages in perl for with features mentioned in the subject

Tags: perl

I need the package having below features:

1. needs client based secure file transfer machanism for getting files from multiple directories at the remote machine.
2. Must have features to do ls at remote machine.
3. Must have functions to know the file permissions at remote machine.
4. It have to use single connection for all file transfers.
5. That package have to use less number of resources and it have to do transfer at fast.
6. zipping the files at the remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this homework? And, have you tried searching [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org)?  There are several modules that do what you need, such as [Net::SCP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SCP) and [IO::Compress::Gunzip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Compress::Gunzip).

Answer (score -1):

You can get most of this done with [`Net::SFTP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SFTP). How well the remote server complies with the compression part is mainly a function of *that* machine. If it supports it, you can probably issue a `site` command to do it.